# How to Delete a directory tree excluding certain sub-directory using Gradle?

Tags: gradle

My directory structure is as below:

```
dir -|
     |
     - sub_dir1 -|
     |           |
     |           - file1
     |
     - sub_dir2 -|
     |           |
     |           - file2
     |
     - sub_dir3 -|
                 |
                 - file3
```

I want to recursively delete all content of `dir` except content of `sub-dir1`

So the expected resulting directory structure should be as below:

```
dir -|
     |
     - sub_dir1 -|
                 |
                 - file1
```

I have tried following code and it deleting all the files except the content of `sub_dir1`. However it is not deleting the other sub directories but only the files within those directories.

```
  delete fileTree(dir: "dir1").exclude("sub_dir1").include('**/**')
```

Result of above code:

```
dir -|
     |
     - sub_dir1 -|
     |           |
     |           - file1
     |
     - sub_dir2 
     |           
     |
     - sub_dir3
```

How can I delete these directories too along with the files contained by them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the problem is that a `FileTree` is just interested in files, so directories will not be returned. However, one can use the `visit` method to iterate both files and directories. This way, you can simplify your solution to something similar like the following. It uses the Gradle `fileTree` functionality, but requires multiple calls to `delete`:

```
fileTree('dir').exclude('sub_dir1').visit { delete it.file }
```

Another option is using functionality provided directly by Groovy:

```
file('dir').eachDirMatch({ !it.equals('sub_dir1') }, { delete it })
```

Still multiple calls to `delete` are required. Also the filter is kinda ugly in comparison to the `exclude` call of Gradles `FileTree`. Direct filtering could be used via Groovy `collect`, which then might be put into a single `delete` statement, as it can process an `Iterable` of `File` objects. However, this will most likely require more verbose code, so I would recommend to choose the first options proposed.

Answer (score 0):

For now I managed to achieve my requirement using following code:

```
Arrays.stream(new File("dir").list()).forEach {
  f -> if (f != "sub_dir1") {
    delete "dir/${f}"
  }
}
```

Better approaches are welcome.